# What's wrong with upgrading kernel in this case?

Tags: boot, 16.04, upgrade, kernel, updates

I always upgrade packages by `dist-upgrade` including kernel. Recently I discovered that  current kernel version is 4.4.0-34-generic which is old. The last time when I upgrade kernel, it was 4.4.0-79. I checked the lists in GRUB customizer:
[image: GRUB Customizer] 
As you can see in the picture, new kernels are listed. But they aren't shown when I press Shift button to enter the grub menu while booting.

I even specifically run the command `uname -r` that showed:

```
4.4.0-34-generic
```

I also run `sudo update-grub` which showed:

```
Searching for GRUB installation directory... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file... /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image... none found, skipping...
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-79-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-78-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-72-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-34-generic
Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-79-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-78-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-72-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-34-generic
Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst .. done
```

I looked around in /boot/grub/grub.cfg and there were no new kernels but 4.4.0-34.
Ubuntu's version is 16.04.2 LTS amd64. I want to upgrade the kernel as my computer's stopping to respond after 2-3 minutes after logging in. 
What am I supposed to upgrade my kernel in the right way? What did I do wrong to upgrade it?

Comment: You broke something with grub customizer. I don't use it and have no problems.

Comment: so what do you suggest in that case?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. It turned out that my grub version was 0.97 which is quite old. I upgraded it and everything's become ok now